# Missing ) with JavaScript Code

Tags: javascript

Here is the error.

```
Timestamp: 16/07/2012 06:05:02 م
Error: missing ) after argument list
Source File: http://www.tfwefffepchat.com/Register.aspx
Line: 210, Column: 411
Source Code:

SendSMS(96892042638,'There is a job equalvalent to you plz visit this link: http://www.twefffepchat.com/ApplyJob.aspx?id=8');

SendEmail('noor.al3alam@gmail.com','Matching Job','sss');

SendSMS(96892042638,'There is a job equalvalent to you plz visit this link: http://www.twefffepchat.com/ApplyJob.aspx?id=9');

SendEmail('noor.al3alam@gmail.com','Matching Job','sss');

SendEmail('noor.al3alam@gmail.com','Welcome',Welcome to Online Job Seekers your validation link : http://twefffepchat.com/Validate.aspx?id=__Page');SendSMS(96892042638,'noor.al3alam@gmail.com You have registered successfuly.your validation link :__Page');
```

Comment: Look at the last call to `SendEmail`. The third argument should be a string.

Comment: Put an opening single quote before `Welcome` in the last line.

Comment: it is very useful to have a syntax-colored editor, what editor do you use?

Comment: @haynar your comment just made me think about colorblind programmers. I hope this is not the case, and yes there should be many open-source editors out there. Even colorblind people can configure the colors to a darker tone for strings and lighter tone for functions I guess.

Comment: even in such cases there are editors which visually indicate syntax errors, and yes the colors can be configured

Comment: Yeah, I configured my editor to highlight whole lines when there's an error. Way to call attention. `=]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error is here:

```
SendEmail('noor.al3alam@gmail.com','Welcome',Welcome to Online Job Seekers your validation link : http://twefffepchat.com/Validate.aspx?id=__Page');
//                                           ^ Here
```

You are missing the opening quote:

```
SendEmail('noor.al3alam@gmail.com','Welcome','Welcome to Online Job Seekers your validation link : http://twefffepchat.com/Validate.aspx?id=__Page');
```